# Is there a 1/poly(n) or 1/polylogn upper-bound for this tail bound?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, specific-calculation

Is there a good tail bound for $\operatorname{P}\!\Bigg[\bigg\vert\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,j})^2}{n^2} -1\bigg\vert > \epsilon\Bigg]\,,$ where all $a_{i,j}$'s are iid, with $\operatorname{E}[a_{i,j}] = 0\,, \operatorname{E}[a_{i,j}^2] = 1\,, \operatorname{E}[|a_{i,j}|^3] = \rho\,.$

The tail bound can be without any relation to $\epsilon$ but needs to converge to 0 as $n\to\infty\,.$

Comment: Erm... What is the event in brackets?

Comment: Is that meant to be $P[...-1]>0$?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have updated.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by poly(n) and polylogn; please use standard mathematical notation. It is also unclear if you mean an upper or lower bound. If you mean an upper bound that goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, for each $\epsilon>0$, then such a bound does not exist.

Comment: Why doesn't it exist?

Comment: I can try to find time to show why such a bound does not exist. However, first I need to be sure that I understand your question correctly. Therefore, please try to address my concerns/questions about (i) poly(n) and polylogn and (ii) upper vs. lower bound. Also, to make sure I get your comment, use @IosifPinelis (with a space after that) in your comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I believe what the OP is asking for when requesting a 1/poly(n) bound is, for every constant $\epsilon>0$, a tail bound B(n,\epsilon)  of the form $C_{\epsilon} n^{-\beta}$ for some $\beta>0$. This is attainable as I will indicate in the answer below.

Comment: @YuvalPeres : If you mean an *upper* bound on the tail that goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, for each $\epsilon>0$, then my back-of-the-envelope calculations suggested that such a bound does not exist, as I commented earlier. Maybe, I was mistaken. I was waiting for a confirmation from the OP that my interpretation of the question was correct, but never got a response.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  I believe that such an upper  bound ( that goes to zero for each $\epsilon>0$ but of course not uniformly in $\epsilon$) does exist. I will try to write it down below.

Comment: @IosifPinelis   Do you agree with the argument below?

Comment: @YuvalPeres : Yes, I do. I have now found a mistake in my back-of-the-envelope calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A:=\Bigg\{\bigg\vert\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij})^2}{n^2} -1\bigg\vert > \epsilon\Bigg\}\,$ denote the event in question. We will show that

$\operatorname{P}(A)\le C_{\epsilon}/n$ 
for a suitable constant $C_{\epsilon}$.

If $a_{ij}$ had a finite fourth moment, the argument would be easy. Given only a third moment, we resort to truncation. Observe that 
$\operatorname{P}(|a_{ij}|>n) \le E(|a_{ij}|^3)/n^3=\rho/n^3$,

so   $X_{ij}:=a_{ij}1_{\{|a_{ij}| \le n\}}$ satisfy

$\operatorname{P}(\exists i,j \le n \,  : \, X_{ij} \ne a_{ij})   \le \rho/n$. Therefore

$A_1:=\Bigg\{\bigg\vert\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^n X_{ij})^2}{n^2} -1\bigg\vert > \epsilon\Bigg\}\,$ satisfies

$\operatorname{P}(A) \le \operatorname{P}(A_1)+ \rho/n$. 
Next, we estimate the moments  $\mu_k:=E(X_{ij}^k)$.

First, $\mu_1=E(X_{ij})=-E(a_{ij}1_{\{|a_{ij}|> n\}})$, so that
$|\mu_1| \le E(|a_{ij}|^3/n^2)=\rho/n^2$.

Second, $\mu_2 \le 1$ and
  $1-\mu_2 = E(a_{ij}^2 1_{\{|a_{ij}|> n\}}) \le E(|a_{ij}|^3/n)=\rho/n$.

Third, $|\mu_3| \le \rho$ and fourth, $\mu_4 \le n E(|X_{ij}|^3)\le n\rho$.

Thus for each $j$, the column sum $S_j=\sum_i X_{ij}$ satisfies

$E(n-S_j^2) = n(1-\mu_2)-n(n-1)\mu_1^2$ so $|E(n-S_j^2)| \le \rho$ (assuming   $n>\rho$.)

Moreover,

$\operatorname{Var}(n-S_j^2) \le E(S_j^4)\le n\mu_4 +4n^2 |\mu_3 \mu_1|+3n^2{\mu_2}^2+ 6n^3 \mu_2 {\mu_1}^2 + n^4\mu_1^4 \le 5\rho n^2$,

provided that $n>\rho$. Here the constant 5 is not optimal, and we used $\rho \ge 1$ to simplify.

Therefore $S=\sum_j (n-S_j^2)$ satisfies (assuming $n>\rho$):
$E(S^2)= \operatorname{Var}(S)+ (E[S])^2 \le 5\rho n^3 +n^2\rho^2\le 6\rho n^3$.

Finally, for  $\epsilon>0$ and  $n >\rho$, we have

$\operatorname{P}(A_1)=\operatorname{P}(|S|>n^2 \epsilon) \le 
E(S^2)/(n^4\epsilon^2) \le 6\rho/(n\epsilon^2)$,

whence $\operatorname{P}(A)  \le 6\rho/(n\epsilon^2) +\rho/n$.

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening solution. And I think there is a small mistake that $\operatorname{E}\!\big[n-S_j^2\big] = n - n \mu_2 - n(n-1)\mu_1^2\,,$ but the proof still holds.

Comment: Thanks, that small mistake is now corrected above. Can you accept the answer?

Comment: @Pascalprimer : As a new contributor, please see the guidelines at https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Pascalprimer    From: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see screenshot below)
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.